# How do you increase the token expiration time for a boto3.s3.transfer download?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3's s3.transfer to download several 4GB+ files from s3. All but one were able to download, but the one that failed gave the following error:

```
ERROR: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the GetObject operation: The provided token has expired.
```

I am using it the same way it is document at http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html

```
s3_client = session.client('s3')
transfer = S3Transfer(s3_client)
# Download s3://bucket/key to /tmp/myfile
transfer.download_file('bucket', 'key', '/tmp/myfile')
```

Is there a way to increase the expiration time of the signed url used inside boto3?

In case it is relevant, I am using Cognito to get the credentials, and with them, a session

```
    client = boto3.client('cognito-identity', AWS_REGION)

    # credentials[] contains the IdentityId and Token I get from my server
    # which I get using client.get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity 
    # with TokenDuration=86400
    resp = client.get_credentials_for_identity(IdentityId=credentials['IdentityId'],
                                               Logins={'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': credentials['Token']})

    # The resp contains the actual temporary AWS secret/access codes and a session token, to be
    # used with the rest of the AWS APIs
    secretKey = resp['Credentials']['SecretKey']
    accessKey = resp['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    sessionToken = resp['Credentials']['SessionToken']

    session = Session(aws_access_key_id=accessKey,
                      aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,
                      aws_session_token=sessionToken,
                      region_name=AWS_REGION)

    s3_client = session.client('s3')
```

Comment: How does your code receive the access key / secret key ?  My guess from your question is that the code runs on an EC2 instance with an IAM role attached to it.  Is this correct ?  Or are you passing the AK/SK with a configuration file ? ENV variable ?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I use cognito to get the secret key, access key and session token.

Comment: Updated OP with code showing how I really get the session and s3 client

Comment: Thank you - this is relevant as credentials returned by Cognito are temporary, unlike hardcoded / configuration file based ones.  Let me have a look at this.

Comment: I went back to look at the server side, and I see it uses a token duration, which is set to 86400. I also confirmed that the code is supposed to be getting a new token before every file is downloaded, but maybe the period gets cached and not refreshed?

Comment: I am not sure Boto3 will refresh Cognito credentials automatically.  Boto3 does refresh temporary credentials when they are provided by STS.  Please provide a link to documentation to confirm Boto3 automatically renew *Cognito* provided credentials.

Comment: I also wonder about your use case for Cognito.  Cognito is usually used from Mobile application web site (hence all the doc examples about Android, iOS, Javascript, Xamarin etc ...) As you are using Python code, I wonder where this code is running from and why you chose Cognito

Comment: This is a stand alone client script used by more than DevOps people so rather than managing IAMs forever, the script authenticates with my server and then gets cognito credentials to allow the client to use some selected bito3 functionality including the s3.transfer. In this particular case, the client is running on Azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is not linked to S3 signed URL as you are supposing.

Cognito is build on top of an IAM service called Security Token Service (STS).  This service allows to generate temporary credentials (access key and secret key) by assuming a role (IAM user, EC2 instance, Lambda function etc ...) or by providing Web Identity token, for federated identities scenarios, using Google, Facebook, Amazon.

These credentials are limited in scope (to whatever IAM Role you have defined) and in time, between 15 secs and several hours, depending on the use case.

The credentials you are obtaining through Cognito are generated by STS.  At low level, STS API allows to specify how long you want these credentials to stay valid (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) .  However, I can not find an equivalent in Cognito API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html). I would love to be proven wrong on that point.

Why do you see the error ?

My guess, based on the elements you provided, is that your download code is running longer than the life of the temporary credentials you received.  First download works, but later does not.

How to workaround it ?

- At low level, a clean solution would be to use STS instead of Cognito, but that
  would require a huge amount of work and your will loose all the
  benefits using Cognito (stable user ID across login providers,
  multiple login providers, unauthenticated users ...)
- Another solution, assuming you have multiple file transfers, in a loop, would be to check credentials expiration time, and renew them in between file transfer.  Check `resp['Credentials']['Expiration']` for the expiration time.  You can renew Cognito provided credentials by calling `get_credentials_for_identity` again.
- You can also consider downloading your file through one of the 50+ edge locations provided by AWS.  This is a new S3 capability, just released this week, that considerably speed up the upload or download of large files.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html for more details.  There is price tag associated to that usage, see http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: I have forgotten that cognito was generating temp tokens but I can see now the problem is in there. Something is still going on as the token should last for 24hrs but with this, I know what to debug